# two bouncing balls always linking up in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter, drawing

I'm trying to create a couple of bouncing balls but for some reason, they keep meeting up in the same coordinates even though they have different speeds and starting coordinates. If you run the code below, you will see that after a little while one of the balls is going to get stuck in the corner then the other one is going to follow it as one ball for the rest of the animation even they both have different speeds..

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import *
from random import randint, choice

myInterface = tk.Tk()
s = tk.Canvas(myInterface, width=800, height=800, background="black")
s.pack()



d = 75 

spdx = 8
spdy = 4.5 * -1

spdxb = 10 * -1
spdyb = 5 

xblock1 = 0
yblock1 = 0
xblock2 = 800
yblock2 = 800

x1 = randint(475,725)
y1 = randint(475,725)

x1b = randint(75,375)
y1b = randint(75,375)

color = ["yellow", "hot pink","deep skyblue","dark green"]
c = choice(color)
while True:
    ##c = choice(color) activate for disco mode!!
    x1 = x1 + spdx
    y1 = y1 - spdy
    x2 = x1 + d
    y2 = y1 + d

    x1b = x1b + spdx
    y1b = y1b - spdy
    x2b = x1b + d
    y2b = y1b + d


    firstball = s.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill=c)
    secondball = s.create_oval(x1b,y1b, x2b,y2b, fill =c)

    #A1
    if x1 <= xblock1:
        x1 = xblock1
        x2 = x1 + d
        spdx = spdx * -1
    #B1  
    if x1b <= xblock1:
        x1b = xblock1
        x2b = x1b + d
        spdxb = spdxb * -1
    #A2
    if x2 >= xblock2:
        x2 = xblock2
        x1 = x2 - d
        spdx = spdx * -1
    #B2
    if x2b >= xblock2:
        x2b = xblock2
        x1b = x2b - d
        spdxb = spdxb * -1
    #A3
    if y1 <= yblock1:
        y1 = yblock1
        y2 = y1 + d
        spdy = spdy * -1
    #B3
    if y1b <= yblock1:
        y1b = yblock1
        y2b = y1b + d
        spdyb = spdyb * -1
    #A4
    if y2 >= yblock2:
        y2 = yblock2
        y1 = y2 - d
        spdy = spdy * -1

    #B4
    if y2b >= yblock2:
        y2b = yblock2
        y1b = y2b - d
        spdyb = spdyb * -1


    s.update()
    sleep(0.03)
    s.delete(firstball,secondball)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `spdx` and `spdy` to update ball 2, instead of `spdxb` and `spdyb`.

So, when ball 2 hits the left edge, it just flips `spdxb` back and forth once per frame. This does nothing, because you aren't using `spdxb` for anything. Meanwhile, `spdx`, which you're using for both balls, doesn't flip until ball 1 also hits the left edge.

By the way, this is a great example of why DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) is such an important rule. Because you've copied and pasted the same code with minor changes many times, it's very easy to get one of those minor changes wrong and not be able to see it. Especially in code you've been staring at for hours.

Comment: What would you recommend I do instead of repeating the if statements?

Comment: @Abdullah How to abstract this depends on how much knowledge you have. Do you know how to define and use classes yet? Or functions?

Comment: @Abdullah [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/abarnert/aa69122ef9aadc81179d499b5ffcb033) of how you can factor out most of the work so you don't have to repeat it (so there's only one place you can get it wrong, instead of 8).

Comment: thanks for this but i'm in high school and I just started coding, I understand like 20% of that.

Comment: @Abdullah Right, that's why I asked how much knowledge you have beforehand… For now, just keep in mind that there are usually ways to refactor your code to remove any repetition, and keep an eye out for them as you learn more Python, and you'll get more out of your studies.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I didn't see that. I'm really trying to improve because I want to do it post-secondary. Thanks again and I'll try to study & understand your code!